# Trying to Simulate my Xcode Project on my Personal iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Currently have an iPhone 8 plus that is running iOS 12.1 and Xcode 10. When I connect my iPhone to my laptop and and go to Window > Devices and Simulators, I see my iPhone but I get the warning

[image]

"This iPhone 8 Plus (Model A1864, A1897, A1898, A1899) is running iOS 12.1 (16B5077c), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."

Not sure how to resolve this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a beta version of iOS, so you also need the beta version of Xcode.

[Download it from Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that!